# Swift 2 + Parse: Array index out of range

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a `UITableViewController` which is basically a news feed. I have also implemented a pull to refresh feature. However sometimes when I pull to refresh it gives me the error

> 'Array index out of range'.

I know this means an item it is trying to get does not exist but can you tell me why? Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    refresh()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

and the refresh() function:

```
func refresh() {

    //get username and match with userId
    let getUser = PFUser.query()
    getUser?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            //clean arrays and dictionaries so we don't get indexing error
            self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    //make userId = username
                    self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username!
                }
            }
        }
    })

    let getPost = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    getPost.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in objects {

                self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)
                self.usernames.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are removing everything from `users` and then trying to access it in `getPost.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Specifically, `self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)` is called just before `self.usernames.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!)`.

Also, be aware that the two queries execute ***asynchronously***. You have no guarantee that `users` has been populated when the second query's completion block is reached. You will most likely want to restructure your two queries into [one compound query](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound-queries) or nest them (not recommended).

Lastly, from the looks of it, you may want to use `removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` rather than keeping the capacity with `removeAll(keepCapacity: true)`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I did remove that line before I asked this but did not update my code. I will edit my question now.

Comment: It was removed from the wrong section. The error is occurring in the `getPost` section